Creating react create-next-app@latest project deadloop
I have a problem with creating this React app, simply put after 1 half hour it is still loading. I have restarted it several times since this morning at 8. (Ubuntu 22.04) (Node v22.5.0)
I've tried rebooting the system, restarting the installation, reinstalling nodejs, searching google or stack for something that can help me.

Node 22.5 is broken - https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/53902. Generally stick with the Current LTS (20.15.1).

there is currently a bug in this node version. The official statement has been made and the recommended version is 22.4.1.

Ok, thanks i'll try to install previously version
